# how to create an object in real time by extruding

Tags: scripting, game-engine

I want to extrude an object in blender game engine to model a terrain. Suggestions please.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The BGE does not support mesh creation.

You can modify the positions of vertexes (= mesh deformation). The vertices needs to exist already.